# Why doesn't this work (wxpython/color dialog)

Tags: python, wxpython, colordialog

```
class iFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(blah blah blah):  
        wx.Frame.__init.__(blah blah blah)  

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)  
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour((I put a random RGB here for test purposes))  

        c_color = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, 'Press To Change Color')  
        c_color.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCC)  

    def OnCC(self, evt):
        dlg = wx.ColourDialog().SetChooseFull(1)  
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:  
            data = dlg.GetColourData()  
            color = data.Colour  
            print (color) # I did this just to test it was returning a RGB
            self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(color)  
        dlg.Destroy()
```

What I've tried to do was link a button to a color dialog, store the RGB in a variable and use it to set the panel's background color...I've tested almost all of this, I've inserted the returned RGB directly into the self.panel itself and it works, so why doesn't it work when I use it within this method

Comment: what error do you get???

Comment: None, it just doesn't change the background color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `dlg = wx.ColourDialog().SetChooseFull(1)` seems like a bug -- isn't `SetChooseFull` a method on `wx.ColourData`?

I made a few changes to get it working and commented the code to illustrate:

```
def OnCC(self, evt):
    data = wx.ColourData()
    data.SetChooseFull(True)

    # set the first custom color (index 0)
    data.SetCustomColour(0, (255, 170, 128))
    # set indexes 1-N here if you like.

    # set the default color in the chooser
    data.SetColour(wx.Colour(128, 255, 170))

    # construct the chooser
    dlg = wx.ColourDialog(self, data)

    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        # set the panel background color
        color = dlg.GetColourData().Colour
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(color)
    dlg.Destroy()
```

---

The `data.SetCustomColor(index, color)` populates the `N` custom colors in the dialog. I've circled the one at index `0` below:

[image]

Comment: i get everything but the 2nd part, why did u need to set a index for an RGB, and when I was printing the returned RGB i was getting a 4 tuple (255,255,0,255)...I assume the alpha???

Comment: That line `SetCustomColour` just shows how to populate the custom colors in the color chooser dialog (I've updated the answer to show this). As the chooser does not have a slider for `alpha` (at least on my system) it always returns `255` (full opacity).